# OAuth2 and OpenID Connect - User Session

Tags: oauth-2.0, session-cookies, openid-connect

I am trying to wrap my head around OAuth2 and OpenID Connect. I think I am understanding the Authorization Code Flow. In the end, I am getting (as the client) an access token and a refresh token.

But the articles I was reading then stopped at this point. How do I authenticate the user?

I am thinking about two different approaches:

1. I am forwarding the tokens to the user. They will use it correctly and refresh their access token when it expired(, through the client?).
2. I am storing these tokens and I will issue my own tokens to the user (store it in the session?)

Answer (score 0):

Normally for User Session Management the IDToken is used. You get the IDToken when you provide the openid scope. If you can't get one, than it could be that the authorizationServer you are using has not implemented OpenID Connect.

After you get the IDToken this here might help: [openid-connect-session-1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)